# Reasoning behind $Zero$ validation accuracy in the following ResNet50 model for classification

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, tensorflow, keras, transfer-learning

I have written this [code](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1FJxDmuUlRSC0OWWUlcW50QXeb3d0NS09) to classify Cats and dogs using Resnet50. Actually while studying I came to the conclusion that Transfer learning gives very good accuracy for deep learning models, but I ended getting a far worse result and I didn't understand the cause for it. Any description with reasoning would be very helpful. The dataset contains 2000 images of cats and dogs as training and 1000 images as the validation set.

The following summarises my model

```
from tensorflow.keras.applications import ResNet50
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, InputLayer, Flatten, GlobalAveragePooling2D
num_classes = 2
IMG_SIZE = 224
IMG_SHAPE = (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 3)
my_new_model=tf.keras.applications.ResNet50(include_top=False, weights='imagenet', input_shape=IMG_SHAPE, pooling='avg', classes=2)
my_new_model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])


from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.applications.resnet50 import preprocess_input
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
 preprocessing_function=preprocess_input,
 rotation_range=40,
 width_shift_range=0.2,
 height_shift_range=0.2,
 shear_range=0.2,
 zoom_range=0.2,
 horizontal_flip=True,)

# Note that the validation data should not be augmented!
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=preprocess_input)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
     train_dir,  # This is the source directory for training images
     target_size=(224,224),  # All images will be resized to 224x224
     batch_size=20,
     class_mode='binary')

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
     validation_dir,
     target_size=(224, 224),
     class_mode='binary')

my_new_model.fit_generator(
     train_generator,
     epochs = 8,
     steps_per_epoch=100,
     validation_data=validation_generator)
```

For this I get the training logs as,

```
Train for 100 steps, validate for 32 steps
Epoch 1/8
100/100 - 49s - loss: 7889.4051 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 7834.5318 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 2/8
100/100 - 35s - loss: 7809.7583 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 7775.1556 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 3/8
100/100 - 35s - loss: 7808.4858 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 7765.3964 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 4/8
100/100 - 35s - loss: 7808.0520 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 7764.0735 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 5/8
100/100 - 35s - loss: 7807.7891 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 7762.4891 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 6/8
100/100 - 35s - loss: 7807.6872 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 7762.1766 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 7/8
100/100 - 35s - loss: 7807.6633 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 7761.9766 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 8/8
100/100 - 35s - loss: 7807.6514 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 7761.9346 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
<tensorflow.python.keras.callbacks.History at 0x7f5adff722b0>
```

If I change the class_mode='categorical' it's giving error as
Incompatible shapes: [20,2] vs. [20,2048].